# Call a function in another one

Tags: python, function, python-3.5

I have coded a quite simple program but I'll post a script short enough to reach the main point of the question:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    good_morning()

def good_morning():
    print("good morning")
hello()
```

I've a question about functions. According to a Python guide (written by Allan Downey) Python will execute `hello()` as if it were in the the first piece of program so how can this work if the call is before the definition of the function?

Comment: if the call is before, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Typo: `goodmorning` should be `good_morning`.

Comment: Thank you! So the guide is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Statements are executed in order. By the time you execute `hello()` you have executed the statement that defines `good_morning`. There, when `hello()` tries to call `good_morning()`, it succeeds because the function is defined.

In other words, the function has to be defined before the function that uses it is *called*, not before the function that uses it is *defined*.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is like this then it wont work:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    good_morning()

hello()

def good_morning():
    print("good morning")

>> NameError: name 'good_morning' is not defined
```

but since your code allows for both methods to be compiled before it calls the `hello()` method, the code will compile and run:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    good_morning()

def good_morning():
    print("good morning")

hello()

>> Hello
>> good morning
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this editor online https://repl.it/N2qt/0

the compiler tells you `"undefined variable goodmorning()"` (you have a typo, check the names are well written), and that's because the order of definition of function in python matters, so the code, to work, should be rewritten like this to doesn't work:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    good_morning()

hello()

def good_morning():
    print("good morning")
```

this brakes with:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
  File "python", line 3, in hello
NameError: name 'good_morning' is not defined
```

and the original code (well written) will work:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
    good_morning()

def good_morning():
    print("good morning")

hello()

hello
good morning
```